# SQL Command Parameter cannot covert string to int

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL command to add data from a collection to my SQL database. Everything seems to be working fine except when I try to pass non number characters into my Description field on the DB table. Seems like it's not taking string values.

My Collection class

```
    public class LotData
    {
        public string Lot;
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public int PO { get; set; }
        public string MfgPart { get; set; }
    }
```

My SQL Command

```
          private const string strConn = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Matthew\\QCast.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";


    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    //send data from DataGrid to database
    {
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            try
            {
                foreach (var lotData in lot)
                {
                    using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT into LotData Values (@LOTnum, @WOnum, @POnum, @Description, @MFGpartNO)", conn))
                    {

                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LOTnum", lotData.Lot);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("WOnum", "50-50-100");
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("POnum", lotData.PO);
                        command.Parameters.Add("Description",SqlDbType.Text , lotData.Description);
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MFGpartNO", lotData.MfgPart);

                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

I have an issue with this line -

```
command.Parameters.Add("Description",SqlDbType.Text , lotData.Description);
```

The error I get 'cannot covert from stirng to int'. I don't want an int I want a string

I have also tried:

```
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Description",lotData.Description);
```

Then I get the runtime exception - Operand type clash: int is incompatible with text'

My SQL table setup is this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LotData] (
    [TransID]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [WOnum]       NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    [LOTnum]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Description] TEXT          NULL,
    [POnum]       INT           NULL,
    [MFGpartNO]   NCHAR (10)    NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LotData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TransID] ASC)
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: If you insert then always use the column names: `insert into t (col1, col2) values ('x1', 'x2')`

Comment: Specifying your column names in your `INSERT` statement would be a good start. i.e. `INSERT into LotData ([LOTnum], [WOnum], [POnum], [Description], [MFGpartNO]) Values (@LOTnum, @WOnum, @POnum, @Description, @MFGpartNO)`

Comment: Would that solve my problem? The data does post to the DB if I use numbers only

Comment: The error doesnt entirely tie up with your code, however the order of your fields in the code is lotnum, wonum, ponum, description, mfgparno, in your db you have id, wonum, lotnum, description, ponum mfgpartno therefore it seems things are in a different order in your sql than they are, so you possibly have incorrect data in fields too.

Comment: That's it! you're my hero!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is not the contents of the `Description` property, but rather you are trying to pass a `String` type to an `Int32` parameter: see the MSDN page for [SqlParameterCollection.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection?view=netframework-4.8). You will see that the way you are calling it only works when you provide a number because a `String` representation of an `Int32` will implicitly convert from `String` to `Int32`. You should be specifying the column width in that parameter, then add the value by setting the property after the parameter is initialized.

```
SqlParameter parm = command.Parameters.Add("Description", SqlDbType.Text, 500);
parm.Value = lotData.Description;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things to unpack here. Firstly, you should always specify the columns when using `INSERT` so that it knows *which parameter goes where*, i.e.

```sql
INSERT into LotData (LOTnum, WOnum, POnum, Description, MFGpartNO)
Values (@LOTnum, @WOnum, @POnum, @Description, @MFGpartNO);
```

If that doesn't fix it, then yes, if a parameter is meant to be an `int`, but is a `string`: you need to use `int.Parse` yourself. I *suspect* the above will work, though.

Finally; you might find it easier to use a tool like "Dapper" here:

```cs
conn.Execute(@"INSERT into LotData (LOTnum, WOnum, POnum, Description, MFGpartNO)
Values (@Lot, @WOnum, @PO, @Description, @MfgPart)",
    lot.Select(lotData => new { // args, invoked per item
        lotData.Lot,
        WOnum = "50-50-100",
        lotData.PO,
        lotData.Description,
        lotData.MfgPart
    }));
```